# JavaScript - Trying to calculate a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Fiddle **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/d6F4n/)**.

I'm trying to calculate the dollar value of college credits times $402 and display it appropriately.

I'm using this line `$("#moneySaved").val(result*402);`

But it's not working.

**Here's the entire script...**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".input").keyup(function(){
          var val1 = +$(".creditsPerClass").val();
          var val2 = +$(".classesTransferred").val();

          $("#result").val(val1*val2);
          $("#moneySaved").val(result*402);
          $("#timeSaved").val(val2*5);
   });
});
```

**And the HTML output is...**

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="moneySaved"> Saved on the cost of your degree program<br>
```

Comment: Where is `result` defined? Replacing `result` with `(val1*val2)` fixes it.

Comment: A bit lost as to why this would be downvoted. I did almost all the work and need a push to the end.

Comment: The reason is that no one but you knows what the variable `result` is supposed to mean. You might need it to be pi, or 16 billion, there is no way of knowing.

Comment: Also what is `402` supposed to be? Magic numbers are a bad thing.

Comment: It's not a magic number. As it's quite clearly stated... "I'm trying to calculate the dollar value of classes times $402". Why does it matter to you what it's supposed to be. $402 is $402... anyway you look at it. The result is supposed to be multiplied by $402. And there was also a very clear attempt at stating the result is the `val1*val2`, as you can see here - `$("#result").val(val1*val2);`

Comment: Could I have stated it any clearer?

Comment: Yes, you could have, considering the comments and down votes, I think that is clear. `$402` does matter, its a part of the computation you are asking for help with. Unless you are just looking for someone to write `(va1*val2*402)` for you then its even less clear what you need.

Comment: That's why I'm here @Fresheyeball... I didn't know that. But thanks for making a guy feel like this is the place to come and obtain assistance from other professionals.

Comment: @webfrogs this is not a place to come and learn the most BASIC SYNTAX. You need to do a beginners javascript tutorial if you don't know how to use the multiplication operator. There are guidelines here to ask questions that your question clearly does not meet : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: RobSchmuecker point taken. For whatever reason this post set me off where other like posts had not. I am deleting my answer. @webfrogs I apologize for my derisive answer.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker also for the record, I have experienced far worse. One question I posted got downvoted repeatedly, then a user edited my post to include a picture of myself and an unflattering caption. I agree we should all be striving for a polite and helpful community.

Comment: @Fresheyeball thanks for the apology. You're obviously a valuable member of this community and we all benefit from your input. I'll get rid of my comment(s) too.  Keep up the good work ;)

Comment: @Fresheyeball - I also apologize for my role in this. I should have gone about my retort in a more professional manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working demo here http://jsfiddle.net/d6F4n/4/

Seems you were referring to `result` wrongly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".input").keyup(function(){
          var val1 = +$(".creditsPerClass").val();
          var val2 = +$(".classesTransferred").val();
           var result = val1 * val2;
          $("#result").val(result);
          $("#moneySaved").val(result*402);
          $("#timeSaved").val(val2*5);
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. I'll mark it correct in 9 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Your result variable is missing , so its is showing NaN in text input

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".input").keyup(function(){
          var val1 = $(".creditsPerClass").val();
          var val2 = $(".classesTransferred").val();

          $("#result").val(val1*val2);
          $("#moneySaved").val($("#result").val() *402);
          $("#timeSaved").val(val2*5);
   });
});
```